# can not get data with MysqlSubscription of numtel:mysql for meteor

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor

I am using meteor to do full stack javascript work.And I want to use mysql instead of mongodb.I find numtel:mysql on github, which is a Reactive MySQL for Meteor.
On the server side

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(){

    let array = liveDb.select(
        'select * from tasks',
        [ { table: 'tasks' } ]
    );

    console.log('publish test mysql')
    console.log(array);

    return array;
});
```

on the client side

```
let mysqlData = new MysqlSubscription('test');

console.log('subscribe mysql data at client');
console.log(mysqlData);
console.log(mysqlData.length);
console.log(mysqlData.subscriptionId);
console.log(mysqlData[0]);
console.log(mysqlData[1]);
```

However, I can not get data on the client.And there is a strange phenomenon.From the logs, I find data of mysqlData.However, mysqlData.length is 0, mysqlData[0]  and mysqlData[1] are undefined.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call `mysqlData.reactive()` and check if it is ready by using `mysqlData.ready()` first.

In case the subscription does not work (it does not update the data automatically), you should make sure that you config your MySQL server correctly following the [installation instruction](https://github.com/numtel/mysql-live-select#installation).

For me, I could not make it work when I used capital letter on the database name, you should check it also.